# eclipse - find and replace underscore character in variables names

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

i want refactor variables names.

variable_foo

to

variableFoo

Is it possible to do this using find/replace tool of eclipse??

***edit:***

My problem isn't only replace '_', but edit the next letter to upper case.

Its possible using regex??

Comment: The changing of `foo` to `Foo` is really the only problem - it seems to me some obscure tool out there somewhere has support for modifying a match in the replacement expression, but I can't remember what it is off hand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These links

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#89364
>
> http://www.blog.highub.com/regular-expression/perl-regex/perl-regex-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-word/

seem to indicate that Perl and/or PHP Regex syntax supports a \u operator that upper-cases the match following it in the replacement expression - and I think I interpret it to be a holdover from '[vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)' (UNIX text editor) - no clue as to why it doesn't seem to exist in a more modern and popular regex implementation

So, if you can get your code onto a system that supports an appropriate version of vi (or an editor that fully supports this perl syntax), and then figure out how to open your documents in it, how to run a find-replace, etc.. then you'd have to use an expression like the following:

```
/\b(\w+?)_(\w+)/$1\u$2/
```

or

```
find:     \b(\w+?)_(\w+)
replace:  $1\u$2
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin available in Eclipse Marketplace called *AnyEditTools* which addsa bunch of conversion options, one of them is from/to `camelCase` and `underscore_names` (`Alt+Ctrl+K`).

However, Eclipse' Java editor currently (Indigo) lacks proper navigation in `identifiers_with_underscores` - it only works for `CONSTANT_NAMES_CURRENTLY`. (Details here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=67381)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with find and replace is that it's not AST-aware, so even if you *could* use a reference and upcase it, it would do that throughout the entire file, not just for variables.

IMO you're better off finding the variables and renaming them using the "rename variable" refactoring, which will also correctly handle getter/setter renaming (if applicable) and so on, rather than relying on a (relatively ignorant) search-and-replace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this like this :

```
find : (.*)_(.)(.*)
replace : $1\C$2$3
```

And that's should do the trick

Comment: ok @Pierre Lab. But variables like _foo_bar should replace for _fooBar. I tried (.+)_(.)(.*) but dont works. And the letter after _ is not in upper case.

Comment: My bad, I thought that \C would work. For the _foo bar case, it was not in your question ... In any case, what you want to do may require an external scripting language (eg python)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find any vunderscore followed by a lower case character and replace that with the upper case version of that character, i.e. var**_f**oo -> var**F**oo, _bar**_b**az -> _bar**B**az etc.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like Eclipse can provide that, since as the others already said, you could use Ctrl+H (or Ctrl+F in a single file) and regular expressions to find those underscores + characters, but regular expressions don't provide facilities to transform matches (e.g. lower case to upper case).

The best you can do is to find those variables using a regex and then refactor them the way you want, e.g. search using an expression like this: `\w_\w` which should find var_foo, bar1_baz but not _bar, mark them and rename (Alt + LShift + R).

Just note the following: `\w_\w` could find methods,comments etc. as well, since search doesn't know what it actually found (whether it is a variable, class name, method etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but for all these sorts of find/replace tasks, I use Notepad++.  I code in Eclipse, and do mass find/replace across my source in Notepad++.